# Name of the property that the join/meet of a totally ordered set is an element of that set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, binary-operations

I have a lattice $L$, let's say $L = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, with a total order $1 \sqsubset 2 \sqsubset 3 \sqsubset 4$.

I want to say that for $L$, the join or meet of any two elements $x, y$ of $L$ will always either be $x$ or $y$.

Is there a name for this property, or a closely related one? I suppose it follows from the fact that the join/meet of a totally ordered set is the maximal/minimal element of that set, but I'm wondering if the property I described already has a name. Thanks!

Comment: Some authors have named the property of an operation that $x\cdot y \in \{x,y\}$ as *quasi-trivial*. See, for example, [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X99001557). There are several other papers by some of these authors and others which also use this concept, but still I'm not sure the name is standard.